# How to interpret / read the following mathematical notations?

Tags: notation, scientific-notation

In one of the paper I am reading, I came across two mathematical notations which I cannot understand. The author also did not give any explanation. In both, note that $N$ is a positive integer.

Term 1: $x \in \{ 0,1 \}^N$

Term 2: $h\in \mathbb{R}^N_{>0}$

Thanks

Comment: I suppose that the first def means that term $x$ may have only the natural numbers $0$ and $1$ as value. Or maybe a $n$-uple of $0$s and $1$s... (the exponent $N$, but only on $1$?)

Comment: If so, also $h$ may be an $n$-uple of positive real numbers.

Comment: My guess is that they are tuples , in the first case binary entries (only $0$ and $1$ allowed) and in the second entries with positive real numbers.

Comment: Yes, $N$-uple of $0$ and $1$ (but you have omitted the parentheses :-)

Comment: Actually, he did not omit the $\{\;\}$, he just omitted the $\backslash$ required by Latex.

Answer (score 1):

In general, given two sets $A$ and $B, A^B$ represents set of all functions $f$ such that $f:B\to A$.

The first one represents the set of all functions $f$ such that $f:\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$. Recall set of all sequences of $0$s and $1$s, you'll notice that both these sets are the same.
So if $x\in \{0,1\}^\mathbb N$, then $x$ is a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$.

The second one represents set of all functions $f$ such that $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R^+$. Recall set of all sequences of positive numbers, you'll notice that both these sets are the same.
So if $h\in \mathbb R_{>0}^\mathbb N$, then $h$ is a function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R_{>0}$, where $\mathbb R_{>0}=\{x\in \mathbb R: x\gt 0\}$

Answer (score 1):

In this case $x \in S^N$ where $S$ is some set means that $x$ is a tuple of length $N$ with entries from the set $S$, that is

$$x = (s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_N)$$

where all the $s_i$ are elements of $S$. So in the case of $S = \{0, 1\}$ (the set containing the elements $0$ and $1$) and $N=2$ we have $$S^N= \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}.$$

In the case of $S = \mathbb R_{>0}$, the entries are *positive numbers*.